# Getting Current ViewController Name in Parent ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I have view controller as follows

parent view Controller

```
@interface Parent : UIViewController
{
}
```

child view Controller

```
@interface Child : Parent
{
}
```

Now i want current viewcontroller name in parent viewcontroller, I have searched but got simple clue is.

If it is a navigation based app, you can get the current view controller by,

```
UIViewController *currentVC = self.navigationController.visibleViewController;
```

But what is the currect procedure to access the current viewcontroller name in Parent Viewcontroller.

Comment: What do you mean by "viewcontroller name"? Do you mean the class name (such as `Child` or `Parent`)? Do you mean the view controller's title (from the `title` property)?

Comment: by parent viewController do you just mean parent class .. ?

Comment: @rmaddy I am attempting to take class name of current ViewController in Parent Class

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    for(UIViewController * view in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[Child class]])
        {
           //child VC is displayed on screen
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Code below can help. I have not tried it but let me know if it worked

Write the following method in Parent class

```
 -(void)getClassName:(NSString*)className{
   NSLog(className);
   //Your code here
 }
```

Following lines where you need to access the current viewcontroller name

```
 [self getClassName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
```

Hope this post was helpful

Answer (score 1):

I have founded the answer,

in Parent ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIViewController *currentVC = self.navigationController.visibleViewController;
    NSLog(@"The Current Class : %@", [self getClassName:currentVC]);
}

- (NSString*) getClassName:(id) obj
{   
    const char* className = class_getName([obj class]);
    NSString *clsName = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%s",className];

    return clsName;
}
```

When we are calling [super viewDidLoad] from Child ViewController then Parent ViewController was initialized, Here i am taking the class name of the current view controller. So In my Application i dont want to write this line of code in each view controller instead i have written in Parent View Controller.

Note: This work for navigation based app only, because we are getting current visibleViewController from navigationController